# connecting to DB2 database:[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed

Tags: db2, odbc, unixodbc

odbc.ini:

```
[DEFAULT]
Driver          = DB2
[abc]
Driver          = DB2
[dsn_test1]
DESCRIPTION = Connection to DB2
Driver          = db2
```

odbcinst.ini:

```
[DB2]
Description = DB2 Driver
Driver = /home/user/sqllib/lib/libdb2.so
fileusage=1
dontdlclose=1

[ODBC]
Trace=1
TraceFile=/home/user/sqllib/trace.out
```

db2cli.ini

```
[abc]
hostname="hostname"
pwd="passwd"
port="port"
PROTOCOL=TCPIP
database="dbname"
uid="uid"
```

$ ./isql abc

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

while connecting from db2 driver,below error is coming:

```
Connection attempt for data source name "abc":
===============================================================================
ODBC Driver Manager Path: /home/user/sqllib/odbclib/lib/libodbc.so

[FAILED]: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV 
failed
```

Below is the snippet of odbc trace:

```
[ODBC][23419][1403783774.660159][SQLConnect.c][1380]Error: IM004
[ODBC][23419][1403783774.660223][SQLError.c][434]
    Entry:
        Connection = 0x81aaac8
        SQLState = 0xffff9593
        Native = 0xffff9684
        Message Text = 0xffff8d93
        Buffer Length = 1024
        Text Len Ptr = 0xffff95bc
[ODBC][23419][1403783774.660260][SQLError.c][471]
    Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
        SQLState = IM004
        Native = 0xffff9684 -> 0
        Message Text = [[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed]
```

Googled a lot for root-cause,dint helped much,please provide some pointer to solve this.
its a 32 bit linux machine having 32 bit db driver as well.

Comment: I enabled tracing in the odbcinst config but where are the traces shown?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [IBM Support page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21229860), an *IM004 SQLState on SQLAllocHandle* relates to the new security feature.

> #### Cause
>
> The new security features introduced in DB2® Universal Database™ (DB2
>   UDB) Version 8.2 prevent users from using the database unless they
>   belong to the Windows® groups DB2ADMNS or DB2USERS.
>
> #### Answer
>
> Add the userid (the one used to execute the application) to either the
>   DB2ADMNS or DB2USERS group. Please refer to the link under "Related
>   Information" (below) for instructions on how to accomplish this.

Alternatively, there are a number of threads (e.g. [Huge problems connecting to a DB2 database](http://mailman.unixodbc.org/pipermail/unixodbc-support/2010-September/002661.html)) which suggest setting the `DB2INSTANCE` environment variable to match the instance setting in your `odbc.ini` file for the DSN concerned, e.g.

```
export DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
isql -v FS01DB2
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply,forgot to mention its linux32 bit machine and instanceless client.DB2INSTANCE wont be effective in this case

Comment: have you tried looking at their site for instructions on building from source (and then being able to modify). It's been a while but I did that in the past when working on an ODBC driver.

Comment: export CC=gcc
export CFLAGS="-maix64 -q64 -DBUILD_REAL_64_BIT_MODE"
export OBJECT_MODE=64  ,debug after this seeting on linux

Comment: Edit your question to answer (1) what is the Linux distro and version detail (2) what is the installed Db2-driver name and type, and especially its version, fixpack (3) Detail what you mean by "connecting from Db2 driver", show the exact command line (if using) or the source-code. (4) Detail the account(s) involved, i.e. which account has the Db2-driver installed, and which account is attempting to connect via which method.