# Error Trying To Connect to DB2 From web form

Tags: db2

In short, we are having a difficult time connecting to DB2 from our web applications that are developed in asp.net/MVC5. These reside on windows 2013 servers.  Previously, when on our older 2003 servers everything worked fine.

1. My DSN is set up correctly on my local machine and tests successfully.
2. I have attached a very simple JDBC connection to DB2 that we placed on a simple web form for testing purposes.  This fails with the following error

[image: Error Message]

3. Here is the code that we are testing.  A very simple connection.

   Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim strMsg As String

```
    Dim dbDb2Conn As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    Dim user1 As String = "USER"
    Dim pwd1 As String = "PWD"

    dbDb2Conn.ConnectionString = ("DSN=DB2Profile; uid=" & user1 & "; pwd=" & pwd1 & ";")

    'Oleddb Connection works only with MS SQL Server and Ms. Access.

    'To connect with DB2 You must use ODBC Drivers and ODDBC     Connection.

    ' You have to have Client DB2 installed on Your client machine; This soft generates ODBC drivers

    ' for DB2 connections. 

    'Client DB@ you have to get from IBM

    ' DSN name must be You have previously declared in system ODBC sources as System DSN; in this case DSN name is RYS

    ' username and password you have to get from textboxes of Your Login Form and must be username And pwd of the DB2 user. 

    Try

        dbDb2Conn.Open()



    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally

        If dbDb2Conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

            ' in case of success

            strMsg = MsgBox("Connection sucessfully open.", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Info")

            Form2.ShowDialog()



        ElseIf dbDb2Conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then

            ' in case of case of fail

            ' You make undertake any action You want; this below closes the application

            strMsg = MsgBox("User name or password incorrect.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Warning")

            End

        End If

    End Try

    ' This sample is from VB2008 and working 

    ' In 2005 version should also work.

    ' Remember that this sub is only for CONNECTION open

    ' to get data from the table You have to make command object I write other procedure


End Sub
```

End Class

Although this is a web form (for testing only), we are having the same issue on our MVC5 applications.  When I test my local DSN it is successfully.  However, trying to connect from DB2 from within the form/application fails locally and on IIS.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444326/connecting-to-db2-databaseunixodbcdriver-managerdrivers-sqlallochandle-on

Comment: Which Db2-client is installed on the IIS-server, and on that IIS-server is the connecting account a member of local-group DB2ADMNS, DB2USERS ?